# Avoid selecting/identifying features of multiple layers in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I know how I can limit the identification/selection to only one layer in QGIS (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199318/setting-layer-as-unselectable-to-avoid-identifying-features-in-multiple-layers-u)). Considering it's mobile pendant, I haven't found anything within QField.

Is it possible to limit selection, e.g. to only the current layer, in QField?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Project Properties_Data Sources. Check for selectable/identifiable, uncheck for not.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I assumed this would work - however it is really circumstancial, as I can't open these settings when in field (with QField). The QGIS identify tool allows to "select current layer only". Nothing of the sort in QField?

Comment: These settings are honoured in QField, but you cannot change them in QField. In Qfield, all features on all 'Identifiable' layers as per settings above are selectable.

Comment: The idea is that you set the select options of layers in QGIS desktop when preparing your layers before importing the project into the mobile device and edit with QField. You cannot set selection in QField directly but in QGIS desktop then QField inherits the QGIS desktop project settings including selecting or identifying of layers under project properties.